# Why Undefined Property stdClass Error on Latest Wordpress Update?

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating to the latest Wordpress core 5.2.3 I'm getting these error messages on a custom plugin file.

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$addressLocality in 
/var/www/html/www.clientsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/hove- 
widgets/widgets/careers.php on line 52
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$addressRegion in 
/var/www/html/www.clientsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/hove- 
widgets/widgets/careers.php on line 53
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$addressLocality in 
/var/www/html/www.clientsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/hove- 
widgets/widgets/careers.php on line 52
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$addressRegion in 
/var/www/html/www.clientsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/hove- 
widgets/widgets/careers.php on line 53
```

I looked over the file, but I'm not able to pinpoint why it's claiming the property has been undefined. The error message is from the file below:

```
<?php

function hove_get_careers(){
    $output = '';
    $response = file_get_contents('https://hire.withgoogle.com/v2/api/t/hovecom/public/jobs');
    $response = json_decode($response);
    usort($response,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a->hiringOrganization->department->name,$b->hiringOrganization->department->name);});
    // /var_dump($response);die;
    $department=null;
    $count=0;
    foreach($response as $r){
        $title = $r->title;
        $url = $r->url;
        $addressLocality = !empty($r->jobLocation->address->addressLocality) ? $r->jobLocation->address->addressLocality : '';
        $addressRegion = !empty($r->jobLocation->address->addressRegion) ? $r->jobLocation->address->addressRegion : '';
        $location = $addressLocality.','.$addressRegion;
        $actualdepartment = $r->hiringOrganization->department->name;
        if($actualdepartment!=$department){
            $count++;
            if($count!=1){
                $output .= '</ul>'; 
            }
            $department=$actualdepartment;
            $output .= '<h3>'.$actualdepartment.'</h3>';
            $output .= '<ul class="careers">';
        }
        $output .= '<li class="press-job"><span class="details"><span class="title">'.$title.'</span><span class="location">'.$location.'</span></span><span class="cta">Learn More</span><a href="'.$url.'" class="ab-link"></a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>'; 
    return $output; 
}
```

As I didn't create this plugin, I'm not too familiar with all of it's intendded functions. I'm assuming this just might require some updated code from hire.with.google.com or perhaps a property needs to be defined differently due to depreceated code no longer compatable with the Wordpress 5.2.3 framework.

Comment: Which exactly are lines 52 and 53 in your code? I'm guessing it's the two where the variables `$addressLocality` and `$addressRegion` are being declared, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Alright, please check my answer below and if it helped consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code only checks whether `addressLocality` and `addressRegion` are empty or not. It doesn't check whether they are actually available or not. Probably the API the plugin uses changed at some point and said properties are now either not available anymore or they're provided only if certain conditions are met.

To fix the notice we could simply check whether these two properties are set or not using the [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function, like this:

```
$addressLocality = isset($r->jobLocation->address->addressLocality) && !empty($r->jobLocation->address->addressLocality) ? $r->jobLocation->address->addressLocality : '';
$addressRegion = isset($r->jobLocation->address->addressRegion) && !empty($r->jobLocation->address->addressRegion) ? $r->jobLocation->address->addressRegion : '';
```

The following is outside of the original scope of your question but I thought I'd point it out: if `$addressLocality` and `$addressRegion` are empty then `$location` will be just `,` which might not be a desirable output. I'd add this additional check to make sure `$location` is either empty or displays an actual address:

```
$location = ($addressLocality && $addressRegion) ? $addressLocality.','.$addressRegion : '';
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't appear to fix the issue.

Comment: The error message has been hidden by the server admin. I can just see that the formatting of the page looks off. I'm going to try to bring the error message back up to see if anything has changed on it.